# social-auth-app-django problem with DjangoStrategy

Tags: django, oauth, social-auth-app-django

After installing

```
social-auth-core
social-auth-app-django
```

on Django 4.0.6 and including to the INSTALLED_APPS and made everything on documents I got this error

```
'DjangoStrategy' object has no attribute 'get_backend'
```

This error happens when I click on login link on this URL http://localhost/login/google-oauth2/

In settings.py I have this backends

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Also, I am using channels and ASGI/Channels version 3.0.5